# How to automatically skip leading white spaces in listings

Tags: listings, indentation, automation

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`lstautogobble` (`lstaddons` bundle)](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons)

For my programming lecture slides I heavily use the `listings` package with `\lstnewenvironment` to typeset source code. It's a great package (no, I do *not* want to switch to `minted`), the only thing that bugs me is that I have to pass the `gobble=<indent>` option to get well formatted source as well as output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{C}

\lstnewenvironment{C}[1][] {\lstset{language=C, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, #1}}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A simple truth\ldots}
  \begin{C}[gobble=4] % <-- ** This is annoying! **
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf("tex.stackexchange.com: the coolest community ever!\n");
    }
  \end{C}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Manual handling of `gobble` is especially painful, if one moves code examples around and changes the nesting level. I constantly forget to update the parameter in this situations. Ideally, the `C` environment in the above example would automatically determine the `gobble` by the preceeding indentation (that is, number of spaces) before it in the source. Something like the following (pseudo code):

```
\lstnewenvironment{C}[1][] {\PreceedingWS{\WScount}%
  \lstset{language=C, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, 
  gobble=\the\numexpr\WScount+2\relax, #1}}{}
```

The idea is that `\PreceedingWS` magically determines the number of spaces in the current line before the `\begin{C}` and stores it in some macro (`\WScount`).

Is this possible?

---

**Summary of Results (2011-06-27)**

I got three answers, two of which did actually help me:

- [Aditya's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings/21295#21295) is based on ConTeXt, which doesn't help me, but may be a good reference for those guys who actually use ConTeXt.
- [Bruno's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings/21313#21313) is a bit hacky, but has the advantage that it can be applied to (probably) any verbatim-style environment. Moreover, I have learned a bit about TeX scanning from his well-documented answer. It came "right in time" for me to safe me a reasonable amount of work.
- [Martin's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings/21613#21613) showed up relatively late. It is much cleaner as it integrates directly into the `listings` package and is provided as an own package. I am surprised by how little code he needed for this, which for me is an indicator that his solution integrates well and has a good chance to survive further evolution of the `listings` package. I certainly hope his `lstautogobble` package will make it to CTAN or eventually be directly integrated into `listings`.

I have tested the latter two with my lecture slides, which contain ~100 small listings in very different settings and environments (inside tables, minipages, in combination with beamer overlays, ...), so I can say that both approaches do actually work.

To sum up: Bruno's answer became the accepted answer, as it helped me most when I actually needed it. Martin's answer received the bounty, as it is the cleaner and more stable solution which I am going to use in any future project.

Comment: I think that the right approach would be to count the number of white spaces at the start of the first line of C code.

Comment: I considered this as well, however, guess that this is even more challenging as one probably has to hack deeply inside the `listings` package. Another point is that there may be occasions where the first line does not actually define the indenting, for example, if continuing the listing of some longer function. (Well, the latter could count as a pathological case where it would be perfectly acceptable to specify `gobble` manually.)

Comment: Easy solution: don't indent your source code. It doesn't look nice/properly nested but large non-TeX code blocks ruin your code flow anyway! Alternatively put them in external files and use `\lstinputlisting`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: I did this, but have stopped a while ago. IMHO the LaTex code becomes too obfuscated by that: The vast majority of my listings are small code snippets (5-10 lines); however I have lots of them. I also tried `\lstinputlisting`, but figured that it is organizational overkill and reduces the comprehensibility of both sources (LatTeX and listing) quite a bit, especially as I tend to "pollute" my listings with beamer overlay stuff. To sum up: Embedding and indenting them in the LaTeX code really is what I am up to.

Comment: FWIW, I added such an option to the `t-vim` module, which can be activated by `trimspaces=on`. Since the syntax highlighting is done in vim, calculating the maximum leading white space is easy.

Comment: I now released my solution as `lstautogobble` package on CTAN as part of the [`lstaddons`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) bundle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A different approach, hence separate answer. Capture the body of the environment (not in a very robust way, but I think you don't nest those environments), and count the number of leading spaces. Somewhat tricky to get right with the `\endlinechar` and `\newlinechar`. Alas, if some lines are less indented than the first, they will be trimmed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{C}
\lstnewenvironment{CCCC}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=C, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, #1}}{}
\makeatletter
% ===== Helper.
% Use some tokens after fully expanding them: for this, redefine
% \use@x within a group, and use it outside using \expandafter.
\newcommand{\use@x}[1]
  {\begingroup\edef\use@x{#1}\expandafter\endgroup\use@x}

% ===== Environment.
% Give "special" characters the catcode "other", and tell TeX
% to insert the "newline" character at the end of every line
% (this "newline" character causes TeX to produce a new line
% when writing to a file (done in \scantokens later)).
\newenvironment{C}
  {%
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
    \endlinechar\newlinechar
    \LS@hack@i
  }{}
% Look for an optional argument. 
\newcommand{\LS@hack@i}[1][]{\LS@hack@ii{#1}}
% Expand...
\use@x{%
  % Roughly \def\LS@hack@ii#1#2\end{C}^^J{\LS@hack@iii{#2}{#1}}
  % except that some pieces of \end{C} are converted to strings,
  % and one space is removed from #2.
  \unexpanded{\def\LS@hack@ii#1#2}%
    \expandafter\@gobble\string\\end\string{C\string}^^J%
    \unexpanded{{\expandafter\LS@hack@iii\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#2}{#1}}}%
  %
  % Essentially,
  % \def\LS@hack@iii{\end{C}
  %   \begin{CCCC}[gobble=numberofspaces]##1\end{CCCC}}
  % Restore catcodes of special characters and reread,
  % with \scantokens, the body of the environment, feeding
  % it to the listing CCCC environment. Note that the user-
  % provided optional argument to begin{C} is transmitted
  % to begin{CCCC} (not tested). All the \noexpand are there
  % to prevent the full expansion of \use@x, necessary
  % for \string\begin and \string\end.
  \noexpand\newcommand{\noexpand\LS@hack@iii}[2]
    {\noexpand\end{C}%
      \noexpand\LS@hack@countspaces{##1}%
      \noexpand\scantokens{%
        \string\begin{CCCC}[gobble=\noexpand\value{LS@hack@spacecount},##2]^^J%
          ##1%
        \string\end{CCCC}}}}

\newcounter{LS@hack@spacecount}
\newcommand{\LS@hack@countspaces@}[1]{%
  \if#1 \else
    \expandafter\remove@to@nnil
  \fi
  +1\LS@hack@countspaces@}
\newcommand{\LS@hack@countspaces}[1]{%
  \setcounter{LS@hack@spacecount}
    {\the\numexpr0\LS@hack@countspaces@#1\@nnil\relax}}


\begin{document}
  A piece of code:
  \begin{C}
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf("tex.stackexchange.com: the coolest community ever!\n");
    }
  \end{C}
  and the same with no gobble:
  \begin{CCCC}
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf("tex.stackexchange.com: the coolest community ever!\n");
    }
  \end{CCCC}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks promising! I will try it today within my `beamer` setup. With respect to the trimming of lines that are less intended than the first line: I could imagine an `extraindent` key, whose value is just added to the automatically extracted indent. As this value depends only on the listing, but not on the LaTeX nesting level, this would be stable even if the listing is moved around.

Comment: First tests (with about 20 listings) have been quite successful; also passing of optional arguments works fine. However, there is a trailing newline inserted after the original listing content, which disrupts the layout on slides with many listings. I have fixed this by changing the inner `##1^^J%` to `##1%` in the definition of `\LS@hack@iii`. Is this newline necessary for any purpose?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary. I just thought that listings would need it (the previous ^^J is very important). I'll just remove it, then.

Comment: Still testing, no show-stoppers so far :-) For the few cases where the first line is more indented than some other lines I have defined a new `ungobble=<num>` listing key that alters the value of already extracted `gobble` parameter by subtracting its value: `\lst@Key{ungobble}{0}{\edef\lst@gobble{\the\numexpr\lst@gobble-#1}}`

Answer (score 23):

IMHO such a feature should be implemented using the internals of `listings` itself, e.g. by using the same catcodes etc., to maximize the compatibility with the normal operations of the environment.

The `listings` package uses an internal macro `\lstenv@Process` to process the `lstlisting` and other listing environments defined by `\lstnewenvironment`.
This macro is used after the environment arguments are processed and could be locally redefined to count the spaces (then active!) after the first line break (`^^M`, the one after `\begin{lstlisting}[options]`), then set the `gobble` option with the right number and call the original `\lstenv@Process`. That macro actually calls itself recursively, so its original definition must be also restored.

Here now my solution as package. It adds the above functionality as boolean option `autogobble`, which can be used like any other option with all listing environments defined by `listings`, including custom ones. A test file to show the proper function of it also follows.

#### MWE (based on original MWE):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\lstloadlanguages{C}

\lstnewenvironment{C}[1][] {\lstset{language=C, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, autogobble, #1}}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A simple truth\ldots}
  \noindent Normal text as reference
  \begin{C}
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf("tex.stackexchange.com: the coolest community ever!\n");
    }
  \end{C}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Package:

(v1.1 2012/02/04: Now with support for tabulators)

```
% LaTeX Package `lstautogobble`
% Counts the leading spaces of the first line and sets `gobble` to this number
% Copyright (c) 2011 by Martin Scharrer <martin@scharrer-online.de>
% for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings
% This is free software under the LPPL v1.3c or later and was also posted under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license.
\ProvidesPackage{lstautogobble}[2012/02/04 v1.1 Implements 'autogobble' option for 'listings']

% This is an add-on to the `listings` package
\RequirePackage{listings}

% Counter for leading spaces
\newcount\lstag@spacecount

% Some macros for comparison:
\def\lstag@activespace{\lst@ProcessSpace}%  Definition of an active space
\def\lstag@tabulator{\lst@ProcessTabulator}%  Definition of an tabulator

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active%
\gdef\lstag@activenl{^^M}%  Active CR (ASCII 13) character which is used as line break
\endgroup


% Define `autogobble` option as boolean (by default off)
\lst@Key{autogobble}{false}[t]{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifautogobble}

% `ungobble` option
\lst@Key{ungobble}{0}{\def\lst@ungobble{#1}}

% Insert required code at environment init
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{\lst@autogobble}

% Autogobble init macro.
% If the option is active and `gobble` is not set, init vars and overwrite the process macro with own definition.
\def\lst@autogobble{%
    \lst@ifautogobble
        \ifnum\lst@gobble>0\else
            \def\lst@gobble{\lstag@gobble}%
            \def\lstag@gobble{0}%
            \lstag@spacecount\z@
            \def\lstag@spaceaccu{}%
            \let\lstag@restofline\empty
            \let\lstag@origlstenv@Process\lstenv@Process
            \let\lstenv@Process\lstag@countleadingspaces
        \fi
    \fi
}

% Checks if the next following character (read as argument) is a line break (as it is supposed to be)
% Otherwise there is some text direct after the `\begin{<env>}[<options>]` which is dropped by `listings`.
\def\lstag@countleadingspaces#1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\lstag@activenl#1\relax
        \expandafter\lstag@countleadingspaces@
    \else
        \def\lstag@restofline{Dummy replacement of text after begin of listing to trigger original warning message}%
        \expandafter\lstag@countleadingspaces
    \fi
}

% After the new line is found this macro counts the spaces and tabulators
\def\lstag@countleadingspaces@#1{%
    \ifx\lstag@activespace#1\relax
        \advance\lstag@spacecount by \@ne
        % Accumulate spaces (i.e. their definitions) for later re-insertion:
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\lstag@spaceaccu\expandafter{\lstag@spaceaccu\lst@ProcessSpace}%
        \let\next\lstag@countleadingspaces@
    \else% Character wasn't a space
    \ifx\lstag@tabulator#1\relax
        \advance\lstag@spacecount by \lst@tabsize\relax
        % Accumulate spaces (i.e. their definitions) for later re-insertion:
        \@tempcnta=\lst@tabsize\relax
        \loop
        \ifnum\@tempcnta>\z@
            \expandafter\def\expandafter\lstag@spaceaccu\expandafter{\lstag@spaceaccu\lst@ProcessSpace}%
            \advance\@tempcnta\m@ne
        \repeat
        \let\next\lstag@countleadingspaces@
    \else% Character wasn't a tabulator either
        % Set gobble option (indirect):
        \xdef\lstag@gobble{\the\numexpr\lstag@spacecount-\lst@ungobble\relax}%
        % Restore original definition of process macro:
        \global\let\lstenv@Process\lstag@origlstenv@Process
        % Re-insert all collected material or appropriate replacement material:
        \edef\next{\noexpand\lstenv@Process\lstag@restofline\expandafter\noexpand\lstag@activenl\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\lstag@spaceaccu}\noexpand#1}%
    \fi\fi
    \next
}

\endinput
```

#### Test File:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}


\lstnewenvironment{test}[1][]{%
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,autogobble=true,#1}%
}{}

\parindent=0pt% for test only
\begin{document}

Normal text as reference

\hrule

    Only environment
    \begin{test}
        test
        it
    \end{test}

    With options
    \begin{test}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize]
        test
        it
    \end{test}

    Manual gobble option (override)
    \begin{test}[gobble=7]
        test
        it
    \end{test}

    Autogobble off:
    \begin{test}[autogobble=false]
        test
        it
    \end{test}

    With some material on the same line as \texttt{\string\begin} (dropped by listings. The warning message got preserved)
    \begin{test} some text at the first line
        test
        it
    \end{test}

    dito with optional argument
    \begin{test}[] some text at the first line
        test
        it
    \end{test}

    Different indention levels:
\begin{test}
    test
    it
\end{test}

        \begin{test}
            test
            it
        \end{test}

        \begin{test}
    test
    it
        \end{test}

            \begin{test}
                            test
                            it
            \end{test}

    \begin{test}
                    test
                    it
    \end{test}


\hrule

  Some real C Code
  \begin{lstlisting}[autogobble]
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf("tex.stackexchange.com: the coolest community ever!\n");
    }
  \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

#### Test Results:

[image: Result]

Comment: @Martin: good approach as well. I thought of it, but (1) I was too lazy to probe the internals of `listings` and (2) I wanted to maximize compatibility with other verbatim environments which may use different catcodes than listings. This second point would have made more sense if I had implemented the gobble option myself, as in the LuaTeX solution given by Aditya.

Comment: Martin, that is an impressive solution that should go to CTAN, eventually. I am especially impressed by the little amount of code you needed for this. I *tried* to look into (and understand the internals of) the `listings` package before submitting my question, but did not get very far.

Comment: I have found, however, one bug and one caveat with your solution: (1) If using `mathescape=true` and some math inside a listing (I tend to have lots of `$\cdots$` lines) resets the indent to `gobble=0` for all subsequent lines. (2) As explained in my comment to Bruno's solution I figured that I need an `ungobble=n` option which value `n` is subtracted from the examined number of spaces (for cases when the first line is further indented than some subsequent line). However, my (probably somewhat hacky) approach that worked with Bruno`s solution doesn't work here.

Comment: @Daniel: The `mathescape` code seems to close a group and therefore resets the changes done by the `autogobble` option. I made some changes to compensate for this. I also implemented the `ungobble` option.

Comment: @Martin: Works like a charm! You should definitely send that to Brooks Moses (the listings maintainer) and upload it to CTAN.

Comment: @Martin, @Bruno: I have now edited a summary of the results into the question. Thanks to both of you for the large effort you have put into this!

Comment: @Martin: Great macro! But it cant gobble tabs.

Comment: @someonr: Tabs are anyway evil ;-) A decent text editor should be able to automatically convert them to a certain number of spaces. I will have a look on how to add support for tabs as well.

Comment: @someonr: Have a look at the updated version and tell me if it works fine with you.

Comment: Great! I just did a quick test and it looks like it works for me. I don't have time for more testing at the moment.

Comment: @MartinScharrer is there a version of `lstautogobble` that works for `\lstinputlisting`? Google is failing me for this one for some reason.

Comment: @Luke: No. If the normal one is not working with it then you are out of look. No idea what's causing it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer This looks very nice!  One question: `listings`'s  built-in `gobble` only works in environment listings, and not in `lstinputlisting`s.  Is there any chance that `autogobble` can handle listings whose content comes from an outside file, and with the linerange features?  It would be _very_ useful to be able to include snippets from actual source (where indentation is to be expected).  Would this require lots more work?  (I don't know why the stock `gobble` doesn't work for input listings.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Sorry, but I can't say why it doesn't work there and how difficult it is to make it work. I would need to have a closer look on it again, and currently I don't have the time for that.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Ah, thanks!  I might take a look (if I can find the time).  I just didn't want to jump down a rabbithole if the answer was already a known “yes, we have that” or “that's impossible, and an offense to good society!”

Comment: @MartinScharrer Excellent solution, but as has been noted above, it doesn't work with `lstinputlistings`. It would be great if someone could add that feature. As a workaround, I'm using `framexleftmargin=-18pt,numbersep=-8pt,xleftmargin=-18pt` (soure: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/autogobble-for-lstinputlistings), which is ugly.

Answer (score 13):

This is relatively straight forward to do in LuaTeX. The [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Manipulating_verbatim_text_for_dummies) has this exact question as an example of programming in luatex. The solution consists of two parts:

- capturing the content of the environment: in ConTeXt, this is done using buffers. I think that one of the many LaTeX verbatim packages provide a similar functionality.
- remove the leading spaces from the content: This is easy in Lua. The complexity of the solution depends on how robust you want the implementation to be (what should happen if the source if badly formatted, i.e., later lines have less white space than the first line. Here is the *dedenting* function from the ConTeXt wiki

```
\startluacode
  -- Initialize a userdata name space to keep our own functions in.
  -- That way, we won't interfere with anything ConTeXt keeps in 
  -- the global name space.
  userdata = userdata or {}

  function userdata.dedentedtyping(content)
    local lines    = string.splitlines(content)
    local indent   = string.match(lines[1], '^ +') or ''
    local pattern  = '^' .. indent
    for i=1,#lines do
      lines[i] = string.gsub(lines[i],pattern,"")
    end

    content = table.concat(lines,'\n')

    tex.sprint("\\starttyping\n" .. content .. "\\stoptyping\n")

  end
\stopluacode
```

For listings, instead of passing `\starttyping` ... `\stoptyping` back to TeX, you can pass `\begin{listing}` ... `\end{listing}`

Comment: +1 for another example on the advantages of an embedded "real" programming language into TeX. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 8):

I'm cheating: using the file that beamer produces (`\jobname.vrb`) for fragile frames, and counting spaces between some extra command (`\setgobble`) and the following `\begin`. This is limited to one `\setgobble` per frame, and to values of gobbling at most 8 (or 10?).

I think that it would be better to count spaces within the listings environment somehow, and put its input back to what it expects.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{C}

\lstnewenvironment{C}[1][] {\lstset{language=C, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, #1}}{} 


\makeatletter
\newcount\gobblecount
\newcommand{\setgobble}
  {%
    \begingroup
    \everyeof{\@nnil}%
    \obeyspaces
    \expandafter\setgobble@aux\@@input\jobname.vrb%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\@ninthofnine[9]{#9}
\def\setgobble@aux#1\setgobble#2\begin{%
    \global\gobblecount
      \expandafter\@car\@ninthofnine #2876543210\@nil\relax
    \global\advance\gobblecount\tw@
    \remove@to@nnil
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{A simple truth\ldots}
  \setgobble
  \begin{C}[gobble=\the\gobblecount] % <-- ** This is annoying! **
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
      printf("tex.stackexchange.com: the coolest community ever!\n");
    }
  \end{C}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 The limitations make this solution somewhat impractical in real settings, but the approach is pretty interesting.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about this, I note that `\the\inputlineno` holds the line of `\jobname.vrb` at which we are (try `[gobble=\the\inputlineno]` ;-). Then `\setgobble` could throw this number of lines of the `vrb` file, and check the amount of whitespace at the start of the next one.