# autogobble for lstinputlistings

Tags: listings, indentation

In the manual for listings it says that `gobble` has no effect for `lstinputlistings`. Since the manual is about four years old now and after reading  [How to automatically skip leading white spaces in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings/21613#21613) my question is if there is a way to activate `gobble` or even better `autogobble` for `lstinputlistings`?

**Edit:** I have tried `\lstinputlistings[gobble=3]{hello.c}` and it does not work and I have set `tabsize=3`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{tabsize=3,frame=single,numbers=left}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{hello.c}
if (a<b){
    if (b<a){
        //do something
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|\begin{lstlisting}... gobble=3| works:
\begin{lstlisting}[gobble=3,firstnumber=2,linerange={2-4}]
if (a<b){
    if (b<a){
        //do something
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\bigskip\noindent
Using \verb|\lstinputlisting gobble| does not work:
\lstinputlisting[gobble=3,firstnumber=2,linerange={2-4}]{hello.c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** after playing around with S. Murugan's code I came up with this which also sets firstnumber according to firstline -- something I've also wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xifthen,filecontents}

\lstset{tabsize=3,numbers=left,frame=single,basicstyle=\Huge\ttfamily,columns=flexible}
\newlength{\gobble}
\newlength{\gobblea}
% The width of a single space. basicstyle from lstset should be used
\sbox0{\Huge\ttfamily \ }
\newcommand{\mylist}[5]{
%#1 is number of tabs, could be calculated like in listings-autogobble with autogobble=true or be an extra option
%#2 is tabsize, which is set in lstset
%#3 is firstline from lstset
%#4 is lastline from lstset
%#5 is the filename, the only thing which should be an argument and not an option.

% Remove a single space
\setlength{\gobble}{-\the\wd0}
% Reindent a bit by dividing by 1.1, then multiply by tabsize and number of indentation levels
\setlength{\gobble}{0.90909090909090909090909090909091\gobble*#1*#2}
\setlength{\gobblea}{\gobble}
\addtolength{\gobblea}{10pt}
% Check if firstline is defined
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#3} \OR \equal{#3}{0}}{%
% Check if lastline is defined
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{%
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=1,firstline=1,framexleftmargin=\gobble,xleftmargin=\gobble,numbersep=\gobblea]{#5}
}{
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=1,firstline=1,lastline=#4,framexleftmargin=\gobble,xleftmargin=\gobble,numbersep=\gobblea]{#5}
}
}{
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{%
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=#3,firstline=#3,framexleftmargin=\gobble,xleftmargin=\gobble,numbersep=\gobblea]{#5}
}{
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=#3,firstline=#3,lastline=#4,framexleftmargin=\gobble,xleftmargin=\gobble,numbersep=\gobblea]{#5}
}
}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{hello.c}
if (b<a){
   //do something
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{hello1.c}
if (a<b){
   if (b<a){
      //do something
   }
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=2,linerange={1-3}]{hello.c}
%mylist{#tabs}{#tabsize}{firstline}{lastline}{filename}
\mylist{1}{3}{2}{4}{hello1.c}
\mylist{2}{3}{3}{3}{hello1.c}
\end{document}
```

**Update** Now it should work for any font size (tested from 8 to 60pt) and for any basicstyle (tested from \tiny to \Huge). 
Now it would be really nice, if I could just write `\lstinputlisting[tabs=1,firstline=2,lastline=4]{hello.c}` and it would fetch `tabsize=3` and `basicstyle=\Huge\ttfamily` from `lstset{}`.

**Update 7/06/2013**
In [How to extend the \lstinputlisting command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48903/how-to-extend-the-lstinputlisting-command) there is a nicer way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Have you tried something like `\lstinputlisting[gobble=4](hello.c}` and it did not work? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You can use four space indent to show a code block instead of using `<code>` and `<br>` tags, this produce a more nice look of the code, and make it easier to read.

Comment: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). It's also possible to add [syntax highlights for other languages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints). `:)`

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I changed the MWE to show that `gobble` works with the `lstlisting` environment but not within `lstinputlisting`.

Comment: `sed` to the rescue!

Comment: It would help me to have autogobble work in `\lstinputlisting` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now check this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{tabsize=3,frame=single,numbers=left}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{hello.c}
if (a<b){
    if (b<a){
        //do something
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\noindent Using \verb|\begin{lstlisting}... gobble=3| works:
\begin{lstlisting}[gobble=3,firstnumber=2,linerange={2-4}]
if (a<b){
    if (b<a){
        //do something
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\bigskip\noindent
Using \verb|\lstinputlisting gobble| does not work:

\lstinputlisting[tabsize=2,showspaces=false,gobble=3,firstnumber=2,linerange={2-4},framexleftmargin=-16pt,numbersep=-8pt,xleftmargin=-18pt]{hello.c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see that this answers the question.

Comment: In third last line `framexleftmargin=-16pt,numbersep=-8pt,xleftmargin=-18pt` is used to revert the indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question comes first when searching about automatically add gobble to listing, here is a solution to simply remove indentation based on first line, thanks to `\usepackage{lstautogobble}`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble} % <== this line is important

\lstset{ %
  language=C,
  numbers=left,
  autogobble=true, % <== this line is important
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  int main(){
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works for the environment `lstlisting`, but not for `\lstinputlisting`.