# How to remove the leading unnecessary white spaces when using linerange option?

Tags: listings

To be honest, I am looking for people who already read the `listings` documentation completely. If those people also cannot solve it, then the documentation does not mention anything about it. Sorry for this inconvenience.

But at least I can show my effort by providing you with the minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Program.cs}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Delegate
{
    class Program
    {
        // start
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        // stop
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{   
    language={[Sharp]C},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\noaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangeprefix=//\ ,
}


\lstdefinestyle{A}
{
    style=Common,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bf,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green}
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Full Code}
\lstinputlisting[style=A]{Program.cs}
\section*{Code Snippet}
\lstinputlisting[style=A,linerange=start-stop]{Program.cs}
\end{document}*
```

[image]

My question is how to remove the leading white space when using `linerange` option?

### Edit

Consider some extreme cases below.

### Case 1

```csharp
namespace Delegate
{
    class Program
    {
        // start
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }      
    }        
}
// stop
```

The code should be rendered as follows

with `includrangemarker=true`

```csharp
        // start
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }      
    }        
}
// stop
```

with `includerangemarker=false`

```csharp
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }      
    }        
}
```

### Case 2

```csharp
namespace Delegate
{
    class Program
    {
    // start
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }      
    }        
}
    // stop
```

The code should be rendered as follows

with `includerangemarker=true`,

```csharp
    // start
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }      
    }        
}
    // stop
```

with `includerangermarker=false`

```csharp
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }      
    }        
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `gobble` option and the `autogobble` from `lstautogobble` package have no effect with `\lstinputlisting`...

Comment: What do you mean? Anyway, these can be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43686/27635 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48903/27635.

Comment: Today I'm lazy, too...

Comment: @CodeMocker The second link contains at least a partial answer to your question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48570/13450), clarified by a comment by Jonas Nyrup: "In [the] third last line, `framexleftmargin=-16pt,numbersep=-8pt,xleftmargin=-18pt` is used to revert the indentation." So it's not automatic and it's probably more elegant to use multiples of the char width used in the code, but I can see how this could probably be made relatively comfortable. Maybe I'll try that as soon as some time comes along.

Comment: Oh actually I just saw that in the question itself you can find an edit that should pretty much do what you want. Haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: The listings module repeats code *verbatim*. The reason your snippet is indented is that it's indented in the original code. One inelegant around this is just to copy the chunk of code that you want to be indented differently, and then format that as a separate string.

Comment: If I had a solution, would you start another 500-point bounty? `$p`

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, what you're asking for seems very tricky to implement. The best I can do is to base the number of leading spaces to remove on the indentation level of the line following that containing the `// start` marker.

Comment: @Jubobs: I think using the number of leading spaces before `//Start` as a reference provides us with more control because we can specify the position of `//Start` freely.

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction I know, if would be ideal, but `listings` makes the implementation of such a feature very tricky. I don't know how to implement it. Sorry. The best I can do is what I wrote in my earlier comment.

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction I noticed my code breaks comment highlighting, but I just fixed it. I'll post the updated code when I get the Tab characters covered as well. I'll be done after that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution. More details follow.

[image]

### Limitations of the `gobble` option (provided by `listings`)

The `listings` package provides a key called `gobble`, which allows the user to specify a *fixed* number of characters (spaces or otherwise) to be gobbled at the beginning of each line. However, `gobble` suffers from the following limitations.

- It lacks automation: the user has to look at the listing beforehand to determine how many spaces should be gobbled.
- The `gobble` key is only compatible with embedded listings (i.e. typeset using an `lstlisting` environment), most emphatically *not* with listings residing in standalone files (i.e. typeset using `\lstinputlisting`).

### Limitations of the `autogobble` option (provided by `lstautogobble`)

The `lstautogobble` package provides a Boolean key called `autogobble`, which automates the gobbling of leading spaces; more specifically, it measures the leading spaces *on the very first line* (whether it be typeset or not) of the whole listing and passes that value to the `gobble` key. However, `autogobble` suffers from the following limitations.

- Because it counts leading white spaces on the very first line of the listing, it may not remove the appropriate amount of leading white space if the range of lines typeset doesn't start by line 1.
- Because it is based on the `gobble` key, it inherits the latter's incompatibility with `\lstinputlisting`.

### A new key for removing leading white space: <del>`autounindent`</del> `autodedent`

The approach below defines a Boolean key called <del>`autounindent`</del> `autodedent`, which,

- if set, removes leading white space even if only a range of lines are typeset (i.e. if either the `firstline` option or the `linerange` option is used),
- is **compatible with both `lstlisting` and `\lstinputlisting`**.

### Known limitations

The code below doesn't handle tab characters properly yet.

Moreover, the desired behaviour in the *extreme cases* covered in your edit seems very tricky to implement, because it would require two passes. I'm out of my depth! The best I can do is to gobble as many spaces as there are at the beginning of the line right after the `// start` marker (i.e. the line starting by `static void` in your code).

Please notify me of any other problem.

**Update**: I've renamed the key to `autodedent` (which is easier to read and write than `autounindent`). I also corrected a [problem reported by the OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184378/21891), according to [this answer by Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184851/21891). Finally, for convenience, I've implemented that feature in a small package called `lstautodedent`; the alpha version is available at https://github.com/jubobs/lstautodedent

### Code

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Program.cs}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Delegate
{
    class Program
    {
        // start
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        // stop
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\noaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautodedent}


\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{   
    language={[Sharp]C},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\noaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    breakindent=0pt,
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    includerangemarker=false,
    rangeprefix=//\ ,
}


\lstdefinestyle{A}
{
    style=Common,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bf,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green}
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Full Code}
\lstinputlisting[style=A]{Program.cs}
\section*{Code Snippet}
\lstinputlisting[style=A,linerange=start-stop,autodedent]{Program.cs}
\end{document}*
```

Comment: @TheLastError If I polish the code and solve the problems I've listed, do you think that would make for a useful package?

Comment: I think it can be merged with Martin Scharer's package as he also develops addon for `listings`. Please kindly ask him the details.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 I got no response from Martin Scharrer, so I ended up implementing the feature in a small package called `lstautodedent`.

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood I'm considering submitting `lstautodedent` on CTAN. Have you experienced any problem? Do you have any bug to report?

Comment: No. Up to now I have not found any bug. :-)

Comment: `autogobble` was what I needed to learn about, thanks for all the options here