# Remove margin from listings in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings, margins

I am including some code in my beamer document. I would like to get rid of all margins, so I can include as much code as possible. This is the code I am trying:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{comentaryGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\lstset{
         basicstyle=\tiny  ,
         numbers=none,              
         tabsize=1,
         extendedchars=true,         
         breaklines=true,
         language=Java,                              
         keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
         commentstyle=\color{comentaryGreen},
         rulecolor=\color{black},         
         showspaces=false,  
         showtabs=false,   
         showstringspaces=false, 
         xleftmargin=0pt,
         framexleftmargin=0pt,
         framexrightmargin=0pt,
         framexbottommargin=0pt,
 }
 \lstloadlanguages{
         Java
 } 
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\begin{frame}
    \lstinputlisting[linerange={529-550}]{source/cGaussianBlur.java}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(the code I used is available in http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/source/ij/plugin/filter/GaussianBlur.java)

This is the result:

[image]

How can I get rid of those margins?

Comment: Off-topic comment: *so I can include as much code as possible* is **no** guarantee for a good presentation ;-)

Comment: if you want to remove right and left margins for all frames, just use `\setbeamersize{text margin left=0cm,text margin right=0cm}`

Comment: @dcmst Is it possible to do that for just one frame?

Comment: @Trollkemada yes, please see the answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160825/modifying-margins-for-one-slide) and let us know if it solves your problem so that this question can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried to just pass an appropriate negative value to the `xleftmargin` option, e.g., `xleftmargin=-1cm`?

Comment: @dcmst You may use a `columns` environment with a single column (with `.99\paperwidth` as width) to get the same result (no margin).

Comment: you're all on the wrong track, see my answer

Comment: @MaxNoe Well, that's a bit presumptuous. Since the OP didn't post his/her listing, you can't know for sure that the problem stems from indentation in it.

Comment: at least the indent of `lstinputlisting` leads to one additional tab space

Comment: @MaxNoe You're right: the external file is indentend by 4 spaces. I hadn't noticed the link to it in the OP's question.

Comment: The part he is including is even indented by 8 spaces ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by dcmst in [his (her?) comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200124/remove-margin-from-listings-in-beamer/200206?noredirect=1#comment465120_200124), you can follow, for instance, [Paul Gaborit's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200172/21891) to locally increase the text width:

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10pt}
      \lstinputlisting{cGaussianBlur.java}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

However, there will still be some whitespace on the left:

[image]

Why? Because the lines in your [source file](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/source/ij/plugin/filter/GaussianBlur.java) are indented, and `listings` will include that indentation in the output; it will/can *not* remove it.

Actually, `listings` does provide a `gobble` key for removing a specified number of spaces at the beginning of each line of a listing. Besides, Martin Scharrer's `lstautogobble` package improved upon that by providing a key called `autogobble`, which automatically measures the number of spaces that need to be gobbled, so that you don't have to specify that number yourself, as mentioned in [MaxNoe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200206/21891).

However, those two approaches are only compatible with "embedded" listings, i.e. listings that live within your `.tex` file, inside an `lstlisting` environment (or the likes of it). They do *not* work for external listings, i.e. those living in external files and inserted with the `\lstinpulisting` macro.

To solve this problem, I wrote, [a while back](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164610/21891), a little package called [`lstautodedent`](https://github.com/Jubobs/lstautodedent). It defines a key called `autodedent`, which works very similarly to how `lstautogobble`'s `autogobble` key works. The main difference is that it works for both embedded listings and external listings. Only one caveat: it doesn't play well with tab characters.

I haven't submitted that package on CTAN yet, but you can already grab the `.sty` file from my [GitHub account](https://github.com/Jubobs/lstautodedent).

To use it, load `lstautodedent` in your preamble, set the `autodedent` key as you would any other Boolean `listings` key, and (assuming your source code is indented with space characters, not tabs) you won't get any whitespace on the left:

[image]

#### Complete code

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{lstautodedent}

% this is only to write a fraction of your source file to 
% an external file and make my answer self-contained
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{cGaussianBlur.java}
    public float[][] makeGaussianKernel(final double sigma, final double accuracy, int maxRadius) {
        int kRadius = (int)Math.ceil(sigma*Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(accuracy)))+1;
        if (maxRadius < 50) maxRadius = 50;         // too small maxRadius would result in inaccurate sum.
        if (kRadius > maxRadius) kRadius = maxRadius;
        float[][] kernel = new float[2][kRadius];
        for (int i=0; i<kRadius; i++)               // Gaussian function
            kernel[0][i] = (float)(Math.exp(-0.5*i*i/sigma/sigma));
        if (kRadius < maxRadius && kRadius > 3) {   // edge correction
            double sqrtSlope = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            int r = kRadius;
            while (r > kRadius/2) {
                r--;
                double a = Math.sqrt(kernel[0][r])/(kRadius-r);
                if (a < sqrtSlope)
                    sqrtSlope = a;
                else
                    break;
            }
            for (int r1 = r+2; r1 < kRadius; r1++)
                kernel[0][r1] = (float)((kRadius-r1)*(kRadius-r1)*sqrtSlope*sqrtSlope);
        }
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{comentaryGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\lstset{
         basicstyle=\tiny  ,
         numbers=none,              
         tabsize=1,
         extendedchars=true,         
         breaklines=true,
         language=Java,                              
         keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
         commentstyle=\color{comentaryGreen},
         rulecolor=\color{black},         
         showspaces=false,  
         showtabs=false,   
         showstringspaces=false, 
         xleftmargin=0pt,
         framexleftmargin=0pt,
         framexrightmargin=0pt,
         framexbottommargin=0pt,
         autodedent,
 }
 \lstloadlanguages{
         Java
 } 
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10pt}
      \lstinputlisting{cGaussianBlur.java}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice, indeed !

Answer (score 0):

Your "problem" is your proper indentation of your code. `lstlisting` is a verbatim-environment and as such it typesets the tabs of your indentation.

The solution for this problem is delivered by the `lstautogobble`-package:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\lstset{autogobble,
        ...,
        ...,
    }
```

It subtracts the right amount of tabs so your LaTeX-code-indentation is not taken into account.

Comment: Unfortunately, `autogobble` has no effect on external listings, i.e. those living in some external file and inserted with `\lstinpulisting`.

Comment: oh, that's too bad. So copying the code into the texfilewould be the only solution then, I suppose.