# \inputminted: distinct file parts in one listing (equivalent to linerange in listings)

Tags: listings, minted, line-numbering

I want to include code from a file into my document. However, several distinct line ranges should appear in the same listing. Also, I want to use gobbling, and it would be nice to include some blank lines.

If I use the `listings` package, I can use the option `linerange` to include several line ranges from the same file. However, gobbling is not supported for file inputs, and it seems that single empty lines are somehow skipped in the output (line 5 in the examples below).

If I use `minted`, I can gobble and include empty lines. However, I can only use one line range per `\inputminted` command. That would be fine (because I use different gobble distances for different line ranges), but there is this nasty gap between the different ranges. I can use `vspace` to make it disappear, but that does not always work (e.g., if the page is stretched for some reason). It would be nice to have something like this, which would recognize that these file parts should be shown as continuous:

```
\begin{minted}
    \pythonfile[firstline=5,lastline=7]{mymodule.py}
    \pythonfile[firstline=16,lastline=17,firstnumber=last]{mymodule.py}
    \pythonfile[gobble=4,firstline=22,lastline=23,firstnumber=last]{mymodule.py}
\end{minted}
```

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{filecontents}{mymodule.py}
import numpy as np

def mymean(x, axis=0) :
    ''' Here I explain why I need my own mean function.
    Suppose for instance that I want to use axis=0 as a default.

    Keyword arguments:
    axis -- the axis over which to compute the mean.
    Return:
    The mean.
    '''
    return np.mean(x, axis=axis)

def mystd(x) :
    return np.std(x)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    x = np.random.randint(0,100,150)
    print mymean(x)
    print mystd(x)
\end{filecontents}

\newmintedfile{python}{frame=leftline,linenos}

\begin{document}

    \section{Listings}
        \lstinputlisting[frame=left,numbers=left,language=Python,linerange={5-    7,16-17,22-23}]{mymodule.py}

    \section{Minted}
    \pythonfile[firstline=5,lastline=7]{mymodule.py}
    \pythonfile[firstline=16,lastline=17,firstnumber=last]{mymodule.py}
    \pythonfile[gobble=4,firstline=22,lastline=23,firstnumber=last]{mymodule.py}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you wanted it to appear like the second example, except for those weird gaps in the line on the left side?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect. My current approach is a minipage around the `\pythonfile` commands and a negative `vspace` in between, but that seems a little dirty.

Comment: For gobbling leading whitespace in listings inserted with `\lstinputlisting`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151208/how-to-remove-the-leading-unnecessary-white-spaces-when-using-linerange-option/164610#164610

Comment: Thanks for that - still, in my case it does not help, because I need different levels of gobbling/dedenting. In the example, lines 5 and 6 need to be gobbled, while lines 1-4 do not.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, is there a solution for this issue available?