# Problem with gobble listing option inside a tcblisting

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

Please, compare next two listings inside a `beamer` frame. The upper one is made with `listings` and the second with `tcblisting` (form `tcolorbox`). Both use same source and listing options.

[image]

Following code shows that although `latex` code is indented by 2 tabs, once tabs are converted to spaces (`tab=2`), they are partially suppressed with `gobble` (`gobble=2`), but only in `listings` output. `tcblisitng` fails and all tabs are shown into the result. Is this a `tcolorbox` known behavior or a bug? Do you know some way of suppressing indenting spaces with `tcblisting`?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
texcsstyle=*\color{blue},
breaklines=true,
keywordstyle=\color{green!30!black},
commentstyle=\color{red},
morekeywords={},
otherkeywords={$,\{,\},[,],&},
backgroundcolor=\color{gray!30},
escapeinside=<>,
moretexcs={maketitle},
showtabs=true,
showspaces=true,
tabsize=2,
gobble=2
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
    \documentclass{}
        preamble
    \begin{document}
        document text
    \end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing options={style=mystyle}, listing only}
    \documentclass{}
        preamble
    \begin{document}
        document text
    \end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I add `gobble=x` to the `listings options`, I get no error, which makes me think the option is completely ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `gooble` really is ignored. This key has no effect on `\lstinline` or `\lstinputlisting` (taken from the `listings` manual) and `tcblisting` uses `\lstinputlisting` internally.

The following links consider some tricks to circumvent the problem:

[autogobble for lstinputlistings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43686/autogobble-for-lstinputlistings)

[How to extend the \lstinputlisting command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48903/how-to-extend-the-lstinputlisting-command?lq=1)

For the current MWE, this could be applied as the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
texcsstyle=*\color{blue},
breaklines=true,
keywordstyle=\color{green!30!black},
commentstyle=\color{red},
morekeywords={},
otherkeywords={$,\{,\},[,],&},
backgroundcolor=\color{gray!30},
escapeinside=<>,
moretexcs={maketitle},
showtabs=true,
showspaces=true,
tabsize=2,
gobble=2
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Listing}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
    \documentclass{}
        preamble
    \begin{document}
        document text
    \end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{
  listing options={style=mystyle,framexleftmargin=-14pt,numbersep=-7pt,xleftmargin=-14pt},
  listing only,
   }
    \documentclass{}
        preamble
    \begin{document}
        document text
    \end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `showspaces` this would look OK. Another option for `tcblisting` would be to play with the `left` key to shift everything to the left.

Hopefully, `\lstinputlisting` will support `gobble` some day.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple example to artificially gobble leading spaces (or tabs) in a `\begin{tcblisting}` block. That is, based on @ThomasFSturm's `tcolorbox` package and his above example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
% Uncomment to reverse the default  order.
%\tcbset{text and listing} 

 % tabsize: increasing this increases the xleftmargin required.
 % xleftmargin: only acts on the text, rather than the listing. 
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    tabsize=1,
    xleftmargin=-14pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

    \begin{tcblisting}{
            listing options={style=mystyle},
            title=Nibh nunc massa mauris enim dolor}
        Quis libero Ut habitant Phas \LaTeX.
    \end{tcblisting}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without styling the undesirable result is:

[image]
In my IDE I've got intents set to tabs (rather than spaces) and each tab is set to equal 4 spaces. Nevertheless in the code above`tabsize` is set to 1 in order to keep the required multiple of `xleftmargin` low. It's strange behaviour but it produces the required result in my environment.

Thomas, your package is very impressive.