# Unindent code inserted with \lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, indentation, verbatim

Is it possible to unindent the code inserted using `\lstinputlisting`? In particular I'd like to be able to unindent by a fixed amount of whitespace.

I have to write a relation on a OS scripting course and I'd like to include the sources of some `bash` scripts. I noticed that `gobble` is ignored by `\lstinputlisting` but I'd like to avoid to copy-paste the code and unindent it by hand. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Well, as the documentation states, `gobble` has no effect when using `lstinputlisting`. Is it impractical to unindent by hand? Do you have a large code section, or lots of files to be unindented? In any event, you may want to give a try to the `minted` package.

Comment: @guillem No, I could unindent by hand but they are about 600 lines of code and I'd like to avoid unindenting too many blocks by hand. I'll give a try to the `minted` package.

Comment: Just to add some information here, the `gobble` option of `minted` package works well on `\inputminted[gobble=n,...]{language}{file}`. It eliminates the first n characters, even if they are not whitespaces.

Comment: @Bakuriu: if you do not need sytax highliting you can use `\VerbatimInput` from package `fancyvrb` It takes gobble into account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `listings` documentation, this is not possible:

> Could I use ‘gobble’ together with ‘\lstinputlisting’ ?
>   Yes, but it has no effect.

The `minted` package, on the other hand, will `gobble` files that are inserted to a document using

```
\inputminted[gobble=n,...]{language}{file}
```

Be warned that, in this case, the `minted` package will remove the first n characters of each line of the input file, whether these characters are whitespaces or not.

Comment: minted is (somewhat) deprecated...

Answer (score 2):

package `fancyvrb` can handle the `gobble` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

     \begin{document}
     \VerbatimInput[gobble=4]{\jobname.tex}
     \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to use something like `gobble` with `lstinputlistings` by using the `xkeyval`package.
The idea is based [on this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48570/127845) answer to a related question.

The basic idea is to shift the whole content to the left using `xleftmargin` and adapt the position of the numbers by `numbersep`.
First we define a command which simply holds the argument passed to the `basicstyle` key of lstlistings

```
\def\lsttextstyle{\footnotesize\ttfamily}
```

This is used when defining a new length that holds the length of a whitespace in that specific textformat (it is used again in the `\lstset` part)

```
\newlength{\myspace}
\settowidth{\myspace}{\lsttextstyle{\ }}
```

Additionaly to length will be needed for the macro following

```
\newlength{\mytemp}
\newlength{\mytempb}
```

Then using the package `xkeyval` we define a new key called `xgobble`

```
\makeatletter
  \define@key{lst}{xgobble}{%
    \setlength{\mytemp}{\lst@xleftmargin}
    \addtolength{\mytemp}{-#1\myspace}
    \def\lst@xleftmargin{\mytemp}%
    \setlength{\mytempb}{\lst@numbersep}
    \addtolength{\mytempb}{-#1\myspace}
    \def\lst@numbersep{\mytempb}%
  }
\makeatother
```

Using the current value `xleftmargin` to set `\mytemp` subtracting the length of one whitespace multiplied by the value passed to xgobble and writing the result back to `xleftmargin` the whole code is shifted to the left. The similar thing is done with `numbersep`to shift the numbers back to the right (their original position).

It can simply be used like

```
\lstinputlisting[xgobble=<value>]{sourcecode.file}
```

Here is the full MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\def\lsttextstyle{\footnotesize\ttfamily}

\lstset{
  language=bash,
  xleftmargin=4\myspace,
  basicstyle=\lsttextstyle,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=2\myspace
}

\newlength{\myspace}
\settowidth{\myspace}{\lsttextstyle{\ }}

\newlength{\mytemp}
\newlength{\mytempb}

\makeatletter
\define@key{lst}{xgobble}{%
  \setlength{\mytemp}{\lst@xleftmargin}
  \addtolength{\mytemp}{-#1\myspace}
  \def\lst@xleftmargin{\mytemp}%
  \setlength{\mytempb}{\lst@numbersep}
  \addtolength{\mytempb}{-#1\myspace}
  \def\lst@numbersep{\mytempb}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the normal code of the full script
\begin{verbatim}
\lstinputlisting{testcode.sh}
\end{verbatim}
\lstinputlisting{testcode.sh}
now the echo part without indentation
\begin{verbatim}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={6-8}]{testcode.sh}
\end{verbatim}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={6-8}]{testcode.sh}
and now three examples with indentation 
\begin{verbatim}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={6-8},xgobble=2]{testcode.sh}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={7-8},xgobble=4]{testcode.sh}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={7-8},xgobble=0]{testcode.sh}
\end{verbatim}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={6-8},xgobble=2]{testcode.sh}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={7-8},xgobble=4]{testcode.sh}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={7-8},xgobble=0]{testcode.sh}

\end{document}
```

... and the example bash script which probably doesn't even work:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World!"

if ( whatever ) ; 
  echo "this"
    echo "is"
      echo "indented"
      echo "and this is an incredible long line to check if linebreaking still works fine"
fi
```

Since I know hardly anything about `xkeyval`, I am not sure how stable that whole construct is.