# Verbatim environment with correct tab handling and special characters

Tags: symbols, indentation, verbatim, code, sourcecode

I'm looking for an environment similar to `Verbatim` which will allow me to say something like the following code (which uses **indentation** instead of spaces):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item We first set \texttt{x} to infinity if it is positive:
            \begin{Verbatim}
                if x > 0:
                    x = \infty
            \end{Verbatim}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and get back **exactly** the following, in terms of the indentation, the escaping of all symbols (like `\infty`), etc.

[image: Screenshot]

The problem with `Verbatim` is that it requires me to *un-indent* the body with respect to the rest of the code, which makes my source code ugly. (I also can't use `verbatim` because it forces me to use spaces.) Furthermore, I can't figure out how to embed special symbols in it, either.

Is there some environment that fixes these problems with a not-too-difficult syntax for inserting **special symbols** and **math** into the code? (Ideally, I would want `\` and `$` to be the escape characters, but anything that isn't too difficult to type will do.)

Comment: The indentation is done with tabs, I guess. But you can also indent with spaces (in the `fancyvrb` documentation you can BTW find this remark: “using tabs is in fact a rather old-fashioned style of coding”). In `fancyvrb` there’s an option `gobble`, with that you can suppress a certain amount of spaces or even tabs (max. 9 chars). Note also the options `obeytabs`and `tabsize`. I am surprised, too, that you didn’t get an error message while compiling your MWE. Normally you should have to define `commandchars` first.

Comment: Actually the shown image can *not* be produced with the code of the MWE!

Comment: I added an answer, where I show you something of that, what I’ve wriiten in my first comment.

Comment: @Mehrad: please see my updated answer with a new solution solving the tabs issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## UPDATE

**Martin Scharrer**'s `lstautogobble` package takes care of the tabs issue using the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package; for the other issues, you can  and the `mathescape=true`, and `escapeinside` options; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape=true,
  escapeinside=||,
  autogobble}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item We first set \texttt{x} to infinity if it is positive:
            \begin{lstlisting}
                if $x > 0$:
                     $x = \infty$
                if x > 0:
                     x = $\infty$
            \end{lstlisting}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The file lstautogobble.sty can be found in [this answer to How to automatically skip leading white spaces in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21613/3954)

Comment: Is there any way to make it look like TTY text, the way `verbatim` and `Verbatim` do?

Comment: @Mehrdad: sure; see my updated answer.

Comment: Gonzalo, that's bad: I already had upvoted your answer and then your edit is so much better, but I can’t upvote twice :-) …

Comment: @Speravir: no problem and thank you. Most of the credit, if not all, goes to Martin and his package ;-)

Comment: This is freaking amazing. Thanks so much to both you and Martin!! :)

Answer (score 4):

In order to allow indenting the code as pleases to you, TeX generally ignore spaces at the beginning of a line.

This poses a "chicken and egg" problem: when `\begin{Verbatim}` is sensed, the spaces that precede it have already been thrown out and TeX can't know how many it should discard at the beginning of verbatim lines unless you tell it (there's a `gobble` option to the `Verbatim` environment provided by `fancyvrb`). Only *inside* the `Verbatim` environment spaces at the beginning of a line are not ignored, because they are significant.

I'm not saying that the general problem is not solvable, but a solution requires a different reading of the input (for example maintaining a count of how many spaces are thrown out at the beginning of the line), which is simply not possible in TeX, but might be realized in LuaTeX.

I don't think that indenting code as you do is "nice": to the contrary, I never do that in normal text, but only in macro definitions. It's a matter of opinion, of course. Unfortunately, you have to live with "ugly" code when you need verbatim material, or pass explicitly the indentation level with the `gobble` option.

Comment: Whoa, so you never indent your code like that? How do you match opening/closing tags then? (Isn't it painful?)

Comment: @Mehrdad Is balancing environments painful? No. :)

Comment: Side note – there's still an option of counting how many spaces there are before the `\end` environment; however that disables typesetting the content line-by-line thus likely lose synctex information without some special handling. Another option would be to re-read the file at line \inputlineno to determine how many spaces there are, although that's costly (re-read the whole file for each verbatim environment).

Answer (score 3):

Let me show the opportunities in an answer (it’s obviously too long for a another comment):

As I pointed out in my comment, you can indent also with spaces, which is in my opinion the better variant, because it’s much better predictable. But, see my example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
% Let us first define a custom Verbatim environment, that saves us a lot of writing
  \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{VerbatimTest}{Verbatim}%
    {showspaces,showtabs,commandchars=\\\{\}}% showspaces and showtabs only for visualizing

\begin{document}

Remember, options ``showspaces'' and ``showtabs'' are active.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First, no change, indenting with spaces (using the \$ sign would
        require an additional definition, see fancyvrb manual, section
        "Catcode characters").

        \begin{VerbatimTest}
          if x > 0:
            x = \(\infty\)
        \end{VerbatimTest}

  \item Second, gobbling 8 space chars (up to nine are possible).

        \begin{VerbatimTest}[gobble=8]
          if x > 0:
            x = \(\infty\)
        \end{VerbatimTest}

  \item From now on indenting with tabs, first line for comparising indented
        with spaces, note that by default one tab stands for 8 (!) characters.

        \begin{VerbatimTest}
          First line indented with spaces
        if x > 0:
            x = \(\infty\)
        \end{VerbatimTest}

  \item Now gobbling one character (here one space or one tab).

        \begin{VerbatimTest}[gobble=1]
          First line indented with spaces
        if x > 0:
            x = \(\infty\)
        \end{VerbatimTest}

  \item You can define with ``tabsize'', how many spaces are represented by
        one tab (here 1 tab = 4 spaces).

        \begin{VerbatimTest}[tabsize=4]
          First line indented with spaces
        if x > 0:
            x = \(\infty\)
        \end{VerbatimTest}

  \item Last in combination: ``tabsize=4'' and ``gobble=1''.

        \begin{VerbatimTest}[tabsize=4,gobble=1]
          First line indented with spaces
        if x > 0:
            x = \(\infty\)
        \end{VerbatimTest}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Yeah I was looking for something automatic (I don't want to change the `gobble` values every time I indent/unindent), but +1 anyway I guess.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You can of course give the option `gobble` with a global value in the preamble definition, too. If somewhere in the document you need a different gobble, you can add it there, and this overwrites the global definition then.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This counts the spaces used to indent the first line and removes that many spaces from all lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\zzz{\FV@Space}
\def\hmm#1{%
\let\zz=#1%
\ifx\zz\zzz
\toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@#1}%
\expandafter\hmm
\else
\expandafter\hmmb
\fi}
\def\hmmb#1\relax{%
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\hmmc\the\toks@{}}

\def\FancyVerbFormatLine#1{%
\gdef\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{\hmmc##1}%
\toks@{}%
\hmm#1\relax\relax
\hmmc#1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item We first set \texttt{x} to infinity if it is positive:
            \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
                if x > 0:
                    x = \(\infty\)
            \end{Verbatim}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `alltt.sty` file and then use `\begin{alltt}` for math use `\(`

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item We first set \texttt{x} to infinity if it is positive:
        \begin{alltt}
            if \(x > 0\):
                \(x = \infty\)
        \end{alltt}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

and also use:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item We first set \texttt{x} to infinity if it is positive:
    \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`^=7}]
                if $x>0$:
                   $x=\infty$
    \end{Verbatim}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't fix the space issue.