# Using lstlisting in subfigure

Tags: listings, subfloats, subcaption

I would like two side-by-side subfigures, both containing an lstlisting environment. The problem is that using it in the manner shown, I get a left margin from the listing that is redundant, and with long lines is quite wasteful.
Any suggestions as to how to do this neatly?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single,breaklines=true]
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Caption a} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single,breaklines=true]
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Caption b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `gobble=4` to compensate for the 4 leading spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single,breaklines=true,gobble=4]
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Caption a} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single,breaklines=true,gobble=4]
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Caption b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This can also be done automatically with the `lstautogobble` package, as suggest by [Daniel in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451271/using-lstlisting-in-subfigure/451275?noredirect=1#comment1134485_451275):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single,breaklines=true,autogobble]
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Caption a} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=single,breaklines=true,autogobble]
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    printf("hello world !!!") // This is a long line sort of command and it repeats itself
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{Caption b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the `lstautogobble` package, one could even determine the number of leading spaces automatically: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings

Comment: @Daniel This is a good idea! Would you like to post this as an answer of your own or should I amend my answer?

Comment: It is not exactly a different approach so IMHO it would fit better to your answer.

Comment: @Daniel I added it to my answer, thanks again for your comment!