# What is the right way of controling number separation from text/code using listings package?

Tags: listings

I am trying to control the spacing between the line numbers and my code with the listings package. Below follows the code I am using:

```
\begin{figure*} [!ht]
\centering
    \lstset{showstringspaces=false, 
        tabsize=1, 
        breaklines=true,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        numbers=left,
        showspaces=false,
        extendedchars=false,
        numberstyle=\scriptsize,
        numbersep=0pt}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    INPORT::[name] => [rec.comp.] @ [rec. port]
    OUTPORT::[name] <= [orig.comp.] @ [out port]
    [PRIMITIVE]::[name]<=[rec.port2]<-[orig.comp1.]@[out port1] [rec.port2]<-[orig.comp2.]@[out port2]...
    LUT[n] [logic_func]::[name]<=[rec.port2]<-[orig.comp1.]@[out port1] [rec.port2]<-[orig.comp2.]@[out port2]...
    \end{lstlisting}
    \caption{single line component netlist of the tiny circuit example.}
    \label{fig:netlistSyntax}
\end{figure*}
```

The result I am getting is as follows:

[image]

I am not happy with the spacing between the code and numbers and I am trying to change it by changing the *numbersep* parameter, as it says in the package documentation, "is the distance between number and listing". Even when I use '0pt' I am not getting the code and the numbers close.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lstlisting` is a verbatim type environment, and crucially spaces are preserved. Your code starts with four spaces, and you're seeing those four spaces.

If you set `showspaces=true` in your `\lstset` (you currently have it set to `false`) this becomes obvious.

#### Addendum

To strip the spaces you can add

```
gobble=4
```

to the `\lstset`.

There is also a package called `lstautogobble` which provides an option called `autogobble`. With this option starting whitespace is automatically removed.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. So as I could understand from your answer, in other to have numbers and code close I would have to use another package right? Any suggestion you could give me here or should I change the question or ask another question and leave this as is?

Comment: @elrhod (I suppose I could have searched this a bit more before answering ...) You can tell `listings` to remove the first N characters of the line with the `gobble` option, so try `\begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]`, or add that option to the `\lstset`.There is also a package for automatic gobbling of whitespace: add `\usepackage{lstautogobble}` to the preamble, and `autogobble` to the `\lstset`. (From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19953/how-to-automatically-skip-leading-white-spaces-in-listings)

Comment: Adding the "gobble=4" to the \lstset worked perfectly! Thanks again.